# Gradle + Dagger + Mockito = null pointer exception

Tags: android, gradle, mockito, robolectric, dagger

I'm trying to inject a Mockito mock in a Robolectric test for Android. Here is my code

```
public class RoboGradleTestRunner extends RobolectricTestRunner {

    public RoboGradleTestRunner(Class<?> testClass) throws InitializationError {
        super(testClass);
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<? extends TestLifecycle> getTestLifecycleClass() {
        return TestLifeCycleWithInjection.class;
    }

    @Override
    protected AndroidManifest getAppManifest(Config config) {
        String manifestProperty = System.getProperty("android.manifest");
        if (config.manifest().equals(Config.DEFAULT) && manifestProperty != null) {
            String resProperty = System.getProperty("android.resources");
            String assetsProperty = System.getProperty("android.assets");
            return new AndroidManifest(Fs.fileFromPath(manifestProperty),
                    Fs.fileFromPath(resProperty),
                    Fs.fileFromPath(assetsProperty));
        }
        return super.getAppManifest(config);
    }

    public static class TestLifeCycleWithInjection extends DefaultTestLifecycle {
        @Override
        public void prepareTest(Object test) {
            super.prepareTest(test);

            TestApplication application = (TestApplication) Robolectric.application;
            MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(test);

            Injector.inject(test);
        }
    }
}


@RunWith(RoboGradleTestRunner.class)
public class SomeTest  {

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        injectMocks(this);
    }

    @Inject
    MyModel myModel;

    @Test
    public void testThatICanInject() {
        JsonObject params = new JsonObject();
        verify(apiClient).request(Request.Method.POST,
                "/oauth/token.json",
                params);

        myModel.login(params);
    }
}



@Module(injects = { SomeTest.class },
        includes = { RootModule.class },
        overrides = true
)
public class TestModule {
    @Provides @Singleton
    public ApiClient provideApiClient(final Context context) {
        return mock(ApiClient.class);
    }
}



@Module(
        library = true,
        complete = false,
        injects = {
                MainActivity.class,
        }
)
public class RealModule {
    ...

    @Provides @Singleton
    ApiClient provideApiClient(final Context context) {
        return new ApiClient(context);
    }
}

public class TestApplication extends RealApplication {
    private Object getRealModule() {
        return new TestModule();
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Object> getModules() {
        ArrayList<Object> modules = super.getModules();
        modules.add(new TestModule());
        return modules;
    }

    public static <T> T injectMocks(T object) {
        TestApplication app = (TestApplication) Robolectric.application;
        return app.inject(object);
    }
}

public class RealApplication extends Application {

    private Object getRealModule() {
        return new RealModule();
    }


    public static RealApplication from(Context context) {
        return (RealApplication) context.getApplicationContext();
    }

    ObjectGraph objectGraph;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        objectGraph = ObjectGraph.create(getModules().toArray());
    }

    public <T> T inject(T object) {
        return objectGraph.inject(object);
    }

    protected List<Object> getModules() {
        List<Object> modules = new ArrayList<Object>(1);
        modules.add(new RealModule());
        return modules;
    }

    private static RealApplication instance;
}




buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
        classpath 'com.squareup.gradle:gradle-android-test-plugin:0.9.1-SNAPSHOT'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'
repositories {
    maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.0.2"
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
            runProguard false
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-test'

dependencies {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.2'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.9.5'

    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.+'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:16.0.+'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.3'
    compile 'com.netflix.rxjava:rxjava-core:+'
    compile 'com.netflix.rxjava:rxjava-android:+'
    compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.+'
    compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.+'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:4.0.+'
    compile 'com.github.flavienlaurent.datetimepicker:library:+'
    compile 'se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:+'

    compile project(':modules:volley')
    compile project(':modules:facebook:facebook')
    compile 'com.crashlytics.android:crashlytics:1.+'

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}





FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':project:compileTestDebugJava'.
> java.lang.NullPointerException

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':project:compileTestDebugJava'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:289)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$1.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:198)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:266)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.longRunningOperation(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:135)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:95)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:86)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:166)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:113)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:81)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:201)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:174)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:170)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:139)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:46)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:33)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:130)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:469)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:132)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.jdk6.Jdk6JavaCompiler.execute(Jdk6JavaCompiler.java:45)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.jdk6.Jdk6JavaCompiler.execute(Jdk6JavaCompiler.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.delegateAndHandleErrors(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:96)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:49)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.DelegatingJavaCompiler.execute(DelegatingJavaCompiler.java:29)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.DelegatingJavaCompiler.execute(DelegatingJavaCompiler.java:20)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.IncrementalJavaCompilerSupport.execute(IncrementalJavaCompilerSupport.java:33)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.IncrementalJavaCompilerSupport.execute(IncrementalJavaCompilerSupport.java:24)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.Compile.compile(Compile.java:67)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:219)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:212)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:201)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:533)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:516)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at dagger.internal.codegen.ModuleAdapterProcessor.checkForMultibindings(ModuleAdapterProcessor.java:400)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.ModuleAdapterProcessor.generateModuleAdapter(ModuleAdapterProcessor.java:254)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.ModuleAdapterProcessor.process(ModuleAdapterProcessor.java:112)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:793)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:722)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.access$1700(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:97)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1029)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1163)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1108)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:824)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:439)
    ... 71 more


BUILD FAILED
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally just said screw it and rolled back to Robolectric 2.1 and used Jake Wharton's version of plugin. Works a lot better. Ask me for details if desired.